# Simple SpringBoot, in-memory map, REST Controller, CRUD ops

Tags: spring-boot

I have a situation where unable to figure out what might be the issue. Below are the details. I am able to run my spring boot app, been able to save records. How ever when trying to perform the CRUD ops via Rest Controller. When trying to get the records from the in-memory map, I get 200 OK response without the data itself.  Although I am able to get get back the String response.("Hello World")

What am I doing wrong? I don't think object injection is the issue in the Controller class. Pls suggest.TIA. details below:

My main Application:

```
@ComponentScan("com.someone.organization")
@SpringBootApplication
public class WorkingOrganizationApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WorkingOrganizationApplication.class, args);

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
        context.scan("com.someone.organization");
        context.refresh();

        
        EmployeeRepository empRepository = context.getBean(EmployeeRepository.class);
         //testing the store method
        empRepository.save(new Employee(1L, "XYZ","PQR"));
        empRepository.save(new Employee(2L, "ABC","PQR"));
        empRepository.save(new Employee(3L, "MNC","PQR"));


        Employee employee = empRepository.findById(1L);
        System.out.println(employee.toString());
  

        Employee employee2 = empRepository.findById(2L);
        System.out.println(employee2.toString());
        // close the spring context
        context.close();
    
    }

}
```

my Entity class:

```
public class Employee {

    private Long Employee_Id;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee{" +
                "Employee_Id=" + Employee_Id +
                ", Employee_first_name='" + Employee_first_name + '\'' +
                ", Employee_last_name='" + Employee_last_name + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

    private String Employee_first_name;

    private String Employee_last_name;


    public Long getEmployeeId() {
        return Employee_Id;
    }

    public void setEmployee_Id(Long employee_Id) {
        Employee_Id = employee_Id;
    }

    public String getEmployee_first_name() {
        return Employee_first_name;
    }

    public void setEmployee_first_name(String employee_first_name) {
        Employee_first_name = employee_first_name;
    }

    public String getEmployee_last_name() {
        return Employee_last_name;
    }

    public void setEmployee_last_name(String employee_last_name) {
        Employee_last_name = employee_last_name;
    }

    public Employee(Long employee_Id, String employee_first_name, String employee_last_name) {

        this.Employee_Id = employee_Id;

        this.Employee_first_name = employee_first_name;
        this.Employee_last_name = employee_last_name;
    }


}
```

my data repo interface:

```
public interface OrganizationRepository<T> {

      // Save method
      void save(T entity);

      // Find a employee by its id
      Employee findById(Long id);


      //public List<Employee> findAllEmployees();

}
```

my repository implementation Class

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeRepository implements OrganizationRepository<Employee> {

    private final Map<Long, Employee> repository;

    public EmployeeRepository() {
        this.repository = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void save(Employee employee) {

        // repository.put(id, employee);
        repository.put(employee.getEmployeeId(), employee);

    }

    @Override
    public Employee findById(Long id) {

        Employee employeeOutput = null;
        if (repository.containsKey(id)) {
            employeeOutput = repository.get(id);
        }

        return employeeOutput;
    }

    
}
```

my Controller Class

```
@RestController
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository  employeeRepository;

    @PostMapping("/employees")
    public Employee createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
         employeeRepository.save(employee);
         return  employee;
    }

    @GetMapping("/employees/findbyid/{id}")
    public Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable Long id) {

      
      return employeeRepository.findById(id);
        
    }

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact that you have `@ComponentScan` is concerning, you shouldn't have that. Also your `main` is wrong. Remove the construction and refresh of the `ApplicationContext. `SpringBootApplication.run` already starts your application and returns an `ApplicationContext` use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `main` method. You are basically loading the context twice and thus using multiple different instances of the `EmployeeRepository`.

```java
SpringApplication.run(WorkingOrganizationApplication.class, args);
```

This line already loads and starts your application and if you look at the [`run`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.html#run(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String...)) method you see it already returns an `ApplicationContext` which you can (and should use).

```java
@SuppressWarnings("resource")
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
context.scan("com.someone.organization");
context.refresh();
```

This little piece of code again loads all the classes and constructs new instances. Which is not what you want, unless you want memory issues and other hard to predict issues (like you have now with updates/inserts being gone).

What you should write is something along these lines.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(WorkingOrganizationApplication.class, args);
   
    EmployeeRepository empRepository = context.getBean(EmployeeRepository.class);
     //testing the store method
    empRepository.save(new Employee(1L, "XYZ","PQR"));
    empRepository.save(new Employee(2L, "ABC","PQR"));
    empRepository.save(new Employee(3L, "MNC","PQR"));

    Employee employee = empRepository.findById(1L);
    System.out.println(employee);

    Employee employee2 = empRepository.findById(2L);
    System.out.println(employee2);
}
```

You also shouldn't add the `@ComponentScan` all of your classes should already recide in the `com.someone.organization` package including your `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class. It will already start scanning from that package.

Generally with Spring (Boot) less-is-more, don't try to be smarter then the framework.

Comment: Thanks, @Deinum Why do I need to create the bean exclusively using the AppContext here? Can I not autowire the  EmployeeRepository as a dependency in the main class?

Comment: No as you cannot autowire in a static field. You could wire it in another class.

Answer (score 0):

Why do I need to create the bean exclusively using the AppContext here? Can I not autowire the EmployeeRepository as a dependency in the main class? Responding to my question here : As updated below: we can use @PostConstruct non-static block, that gets executed just after the initialization of bean properties. Usually used is populating a database. For instance, during development, we might want to create some default users in our database/datastore

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class WorkingOrganizationApplication {

    @Autowired
    private  EmployeeRepository empRepository;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WorkingOrganizationApplication.class, args);
        }

    @PostConstruct
    public void execute()
    {
        empRepository.save(new Employee(1L, "XYZ","PQR"));
        empRepository.save(new Employee(2L, "ABC","PQR"));
        empRepository.save(new Employee(3L, "PXR","CHQ"));
    }

    }
```